# ASP MVC5 PasswordSignIn Azure Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, exception, operation

When i host db on azure and app on localhost everything is ok,
but when i host both db and app on azure i get this exception when trying to log in (ASP.NET MVC5)

```
var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

throws exception SqlErrorCollection
the operation is not supported for your subscription offer type

my connection string is

```
 connectionString="Server=tcp:***.database.windows.net,1433;Database=DictionaryDB;User ID=**;Password=***;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

i use dreamspark azure subscription for students

Comment: This question is off topic for Stackoverflow, as its a subscription question and not a programming question, and will likely be closed as a result - However, Dreamspark for students doesn't support Azure SQL, which is reflected in the error message you're getting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about Azure subscriptions and not programming

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, that connection string is user in two separate data-contexts,  it throw variety of exceptions